# Setting water mark text inside in textbox by jquery issue

Tags: jquery

this way i set the water mark for a textbox but when i typed anything inside the textbox and click on any button then my typed text is getting vanished and water mark text is getting set on textbox again.

here is my code. please see and tell me where i am making the mistake

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var SearchTerm = $("input[id*='txtSearch']").val();
var watermark = 'Parts search in english';

//init, set watermark text and class
    if ($('[id*=txtSearch]').val().length == 0) {
        $('[id*=txtSearch]').val(watermark).addClass('watermark');
    }

    //if blur and no value inside, set watermark text and class again.
    $('[id*=txtSearch]').blur(function () {
        if ($(this).val().length == 0 || SearchTerm == '') {
            $(this).val(watermark).addClass('watermark');
        }
    });

    //if focus and text is watermrk, set it to empty and remove the watermark class
    $('[id*=txtSearch]').focus(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == watermark) {
            $(this).val('').removeClass('watermark');
        }
    });

    $('[id*=txtSearch]').keypress(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(".search-box :button").trigger('click');
        }
    });

});
```

i have debugged this code

```
$('[id*=txtSearch]').blur(function () {
            if ($(this).val().length == 0 || SearchTerm == '') {
                $(this).val(watermark).addClass('watermark');
            }
        });
```

and have seen that `$(this).val().length is always 0 and SearchTerm is blank`. i am testing with firefox. is there any error in my code if yes then highlight that area and tell me what to rectify. thanks

Comment: please post your html containing the input box

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to provide a hint to the user in your textbox, you can just use the placeholder attribute of input tag:

eg:

```
<input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name"><br>
```

[image]

More info: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp

Comment: i guess that works for html5 and not all browser support that

Comment: The placeholder attribute is supported in Internet Explorer 10, Firefox, Opera, Chrome, and Safari.

The placeholder attribute of the <input> tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.